# error while android sonarQube gradle plugin integration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using dependencies  in app module and running sonarqube for app module.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':bluetoothchatlibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
}
```

But it is not getting class files for dependencies and giving "`class not found"` for all java files in dependencies.

kindly help how I get path for the modules to mention in sonar libraries property or I need to set some other properties of sonarQube

```
  def libraries = project.android.sdkDirectory.getPath()+"/platforms/android-23/android.jar"
  def compileDependencies = project.configurations.compile.files.collect {it.path}join(",")
  property "sonar.java.libraries", "$compileDependencies,$libraries"
```

It is getting .aar file in path not the .jar files.

Please help

```
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.StyleRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.DrawableRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.StringRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.ColorInt
Class not found: android.support.annotation.MenuRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.DrawableRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.annotation.ColorInt
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.DrawableRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.annotation.ColorInt
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.DrawableRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.annotation.ColorInt
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class not found: android.support.annotation.Nullable
Class not found: android.support.annotation.LayoutRes
Class not found: android.support.annotation.CallSuper
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23
Class not found: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator
Class not found: android.support.annotation.NonNull
Class 'android/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
Class 'android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

Comment: Have you solve?